# How to connect to an OPC-UA server which requires x509 certificate based user authentication using uaExpert based client

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate, x509certificate2, opc-ua

I am using the `uaExpert` as an OPC-UA client. I would like to make my client(uaExpert) support x509 certificate authentication methods. however, I generated x509 certificate using openssl then I attached that certificate and private key in uaExpert. so now when I am trying to connect with `OPC-UA Server` at that time my OPC-UA server application throwing an exception that is `'CN=OPCUA Server, O=AL, L=Houston, S=TX, C=US' is not a trusted user certificate.`  please help us.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure the OPC UA Server to accept this certificate.

The server should have a UI element allowing you to add it to the Server "Trusted Store" or have a special folder where you could copy your certificate.

The private key do not need to be copied and should remain on your client.

Comment: here I copied that certificate still getting same exception `C:\ProgramData\OPC Foundation\pki`

Comment: Which SDK / Stack do you use?
If you use the opc foundation .net stack you need to copy the certificate to this path:https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/blob/d65e1cfc27d4f52152a8c2a59c619912b64bcaf8/Applications/ReferenceServer/Quickstarts.ReferenceServer.Config.xml#L60